# Laravel Retrieve the last record of a thread in the model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

For a certain forum, i retrieve all the posts. I can access them by

```
$thread->posts
```

For the moment I can retrive the last post saved for this thread by doing

```
$thread->posts[0]->author
```

But i'd like a better solution like something like

```
$thread->last_post
```

But I need your help I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a method in your `Thread` model:

```
public function lastPost() {
    return $this->posts[0];
    // OR: return $this->posts->first();
}

var_dump($thread->lastPost()->author);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put into your Thread model this:

```
public function last_post() {
    return $this->hasOne('Post')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

Then you can access it like you wanted.